# bill.com creating Invoice questions on tax & itemId

Tags: invoice

Writing an interface to bill.com for Invoice using Invoice.json (have some existing code for Payments -- Bill.json) that works.  interface is here https://developer.bill.com/hc/en-us/articles/208196656-Invoice

When adding itemId to show "our" internal id - I get an error
   -- the example shows -- "itemId" : "0ii01YCDSBIDTPTJbhcb",
   -- the doc says -- Id of the item being billed on the invoice line item.
Now sure what I need to create here to get this to work and show "our" internal id

We have a tax total that we already calculated - is there any way that we can just add that tax total to show in the invoice?  It seems more complicated than that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer with helped by folks at bill.com - Thank you!!!

Basically you need to create a bill.com "Item" object. https://developer.bill.com/hc/en-us/articles/208196666

To have your ow "Order Num" in the order field line item, create a new "Item" object and make the "description" field = to your order num.  Use the return ID from the creation and assign it to invoiceLineItems.itemId (in the example "itemId" : "0ii01YCDSBIDTPTJbhcb",)

Tax object is also an "Item" object - created with the same interface above.  Set the type = 6 (for sales Tax) and perform similar to above the create the item object.  Use that returning ID and assign it to Invoice.itemSalesTax.  This is the sales tax used for all the items in your invoiceLineItems area.  Set taxable to true for those line items you want to be tax caclculated

The sales tax "Item" object creation will look like the following:

{
    "entity" : "Item",
    "name" : "My Tax",
    "type" : "6",
    "description" : "CA State",
    "percentage" : 8,
 }

Hope this helps someone else